# What is the easiest way for me to get a sliding keyboard for my desk?

Tags: furniture

I'm very inexperienced with furniture, so I'd prefer an option that can work for inexperienced people.

Basically I'm wondering - is it easier to buy a desk first, and then buy a separate sliding keyboard tray later? If that is the case, then what are the chances that the sliding keyboard tray might fall off?

Or is it simply easier to buy a desk with a sliding keyboard tray already mounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the easiest would be to buy a desk with a pre-mounted sliding tray.

Next easiest would be a desk kit that includes a sliding tray.  There are many, many options out there, and since everything's pre-cut and pre-drilled, you don't have to worry about measurements and so forth.  Some basic assembly skill is required but nothing beyond what is usually expected for Ikea-style furniture.

Adding a sliding keyboard tray kit to an existing desk would be next in difficulty.  You can buy pre-made trays to add to a desk.  The challenge is mostly measurement, to ensure you get a kit that fits the desk's available attachment space.  After that it's just basic assembly.

The most difficult would be crafting a keyboard tray from raw materials.  But that requires more advanced tools and some thought to design, so guessing this is out of scope for the question.  Yet, if you got the right tools even this isn't *that* hard...

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for the desk with the keyboard tray supplied. If you get a tray to add on  there are four possible outcomes. It will work perfect,the draw won't open far enough,it won't go in far enough or your legs won't fit under the desk. Mounting an add-on would require some measurement taking and maybe some drilling and screwdriving. Getting a desk with it supplied the holes will be predrilled, the hardware won't come thru the desk top and the height will be sufficient to allow a chair to slide under the desk.